How to write better try-catch blocks with variable assignments?
Everyone knows the following situation: you want to assign a variable, but have to catch an exception, and in that case assign a fallback value.
This always results at least in a 6-liner, while you just want a simple fallback value and maybe don't care about the exception.
How can the following be optimized in terms for reading or boilerplate code, if possible?
            List<String> mylist;
            try {
                mylist = readFile(resource);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                mylist = List.of();
            }

I'm looking for some kind of the following (which is of course pseudocode), but to illustrate what my goal is:
List<String> mylist = if (success) ? readFile(resource) : List.of();


You may want to look into vavr.

I don't want to add additional libs. But yes, from the type of written code that's similar to what I'm looking for.

As I think you've gathered from the answers here: with bare Java, you are pretty much stuck with this; you could add lambdas or other things, but those are only going to clean it up so much.

If you don't want to add more libraries, you can use a helper method and define your own supplier interface throwing an exception.
@FunctionalInterface
public interface ThrowingSupplier<T> {

  T get() throws Exception;
}

The helper:
public class Helper {

  public static <T> T computeOrElse(ThrowingSupplier<T> computation, Function<Exception, T> errorHandler) {
    try {
      return computation.get();
    } catch (Exception exc) {
      return errorHandler.apply(exc);
    }
  }
}

The fallback error handler is a function accepting the exception - this gives you the flexibility to handle it however you want.
Example usages:
List<String> res = Helper.computeOrElse(() -> readFile(resource), e -> List.of());
List<String> res2 = Helper.computeOrElse(() -> readFile(resource), e -> {
  LOGGER.error("Could not read file, using fallback", e);
  return List.of();
});
List<String> res3 = Helper.computeOrElse(() -> readFile(resource), e -> {
  throw new RuntimeException(e);
});


Great! I think that is as close as we can get with bare java.

Note that you can also make the exception generic: <T, X extends Throwable> and then T get() throw X, etc. Depending on how you use it, that could make the exception handling stronger typed.

Here is simple snippet
public class AppTest {
    @Test
    public void test() {
        int i = Try.me(() -> Integer.parseInt("x"))
                .orElse(0);
    }

    static class Try {
        public static <T> Optional<T> me(Supplier<T> s) {
            try {
                return Optional.of(s.get());
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                return Optional.empty();
            }
        }
    }
}

It is what vavr do, but simpler.

OP: Since you asked in the other answer "what if I don't want the exception ignored" — you could have the Try return a custom ValueOrThrowable<T, X extends Throwable> that's similar to Optional but includes the ability to get or handle the exception.

Vavr
You can also use Vavr Try.of():
List<String> = Try.of(() -> readFile(resource))
  .getOrElseGet(e -> List.of());

Or just move the try-catch inside the called method (readFile) so it will become:
List<String> mylist = readFile(resource);


Yes that's one option, but what if I don't always want the exception being ignored? Okay I then probably would have to create a  helper method readFileIgnoreErrors() or similar?
